# Nested Form does not Display form for ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I am current using **activeadmin** to create a nested form. I can click on the add nested resource button which will display the inputs for the respective nested resources. However, I would like to have the inputs display by default without having to click on the add resource button (i.e the inputs should be displayed once the form is loaded).
I have rechecked my code against the ActiveAdmin docs and also checked various **stackoverflow** posts but was unable to make much progress.

[Picture of how the form current looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciNtq.png)

My code is as follows in admin/project.rb:

```
form title: 'Create a New Project' do |f|
    f.inputs 'Basic Information' do
      f.input :category
      f.input :name
      f.input :location
      f.input :size, sortable: :size do |project|
        "#{project.size}m2"
      end
      f.input :published? 
      f.has_many :project_main_image, heading: 'Project main image', allow_destroy: true, new_record: false do |a|
        a.input :photo, hint: image_tag(a.object.photo.thumb.url, class: 'active-admin-thumbnail')
        a.input :orientation
      end
      f.has_many :project_descriptions, allow_destroy: true do |a|
        a.input :contents, as: :ckeditor, input_html: { ckeditor: { toolbar: 'Full' } }
      end
      f.has_many :project_gallery_images, allow_destroy: true do |a|
        a.input :photo, hint: image_tag(a.object.photo.thumb.url, class: 'active-admin-thumbnail')
        a.input :orientation
        a.input :row_order
      end
      f.actions
    end
  end
```

Any feedback or advice. Do let me know if you require more information.

Answer (score 0):

That's what something i did.

you can take nested attributes like this with for keyword:

```
    form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :user, input_html: { disabled: true }
      f.input :name
      f.input :address
      f.input :city
      f.input :country, as: :string
    end
    f.buttons

    f.inputs "Account Information", for: [:account, f.object.account] do |s|
      s.input :active, as: :boolean
      s.input :subscription, as: :boolean
      s.input :expires_on, as: :datepicker

      s.actions
    end
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit!
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually have no issues getting saving the nested attributes. Just unable to get the nested inputs to display by default...